# Dedupe and sort a list in Python 2.2

Tags: python, list, sorting, unique, python-2.2

In Python **2.2** (don't ask), what's the neatest way to sort a list and remove duplicates?

I can obviously write a function that would `sort()` then iterate, but am wondering if there's an idiomatic one-liner.

**edit:** The list is short, so efficiency is not a concern. Also, the elements are immutable.

Comment: I can't recall if the `set` module was in 2.2.  If it was, `set(myList)` will remove all dupes.

Comment: @g.d.d.c: Already checked, `sets` is 2.3+.

Comment: Ahh.  Any chance it'd be in `__future__` in that version?  Are the values hashable?

Comment: @g.d.d.c Don't think it's in `__future__`. The values are strings, and there aren't many, so don't care about efficiency.

Comment: Future answerers may find the [2.2 documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.2/) useful, to check that the language features their solution depends on actually exist.

Comment: Here's a recipe for sets for python 2.2 http://code.activestate.com/recipes/106469-yet-another-set-class-for-python/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For old python versions, and since you're using strings, there's no one-liner I can think of, but a pattern would probably be this, using dictionaries:

```
def sorted_uniq(your_list):
    table = {}
    for s in your_list:
        table[s] = None
    k = table.keys()
    k.sort()
    return k
```

Adapted from an ancient ActiveState code snippet thread that Alex Martelli himself wrote several comments on: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52560/

A shorter way with list comprehensions:

```
def sort_uniq(alist):
   d = {}
   mod_list = [d.setdefault(i,i) for i in alist if i not in d]
   mod_list.sort()
   return mod_list
```

---

Aside from Steven's neat (yet slightly unattractive) one liner, I think this heads toward the fewest lines and most idiomatic way of doing it with Python 2.2:

Thanks to Steven Rumbalski in the comments, the 2nd version can be condensed further with python's `zip` function:

```
def sort_uniq(alist):
   mod_list = dict(zip(alist,alist)).keys()
   mod_list.sort()
   return mod_list
```

If `list.sort()` didn't operate by side effect, we'd have a one liner. ;)

Comment: This is what I was coming up with as well.  I keep trying to think of a clever way to encapsulate it as a one-liner, but can't.

Comment: Hate to be a pain, but `sorted()` is Python 2.4+. Easy to replace with `sort()` though.

Comment: @aix - Yeah I was wondering if `sorted` was in 2.2, but the docs didn't say so - switched to calling `sort` on `table.keys()`.

Comment: On your second version you could get rid of referring to the intermediate dict and do `mod_list = dict(zip(alist, alist)).keys()`

Comment: @birryree:  I ended up liking that enough that I added a modified version to my answer.

Comment: @birryree: Awesome, I think the third version is as close to an idiomatic one-liner as we're going to get.

Comment: Here's my best attempt at a one-liner.  `x = x.sort() or [s for s, t in zip(x, x[1:] + [None]) if s != t]` where `x` is the original list.

Comment: A tiny bit shorter `x = x.sort() or [s for s, t in map(None, x, x[1:]) if s != t]`

Answer (score 5):

Idiomatic *and* a one-liner?  No.

Here's a non-idiomatic butt-ugly one-liner.

```
>>> x = [4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1]
>>> [y for y in (locals().__setitem__('d',{}) or x.sort() or x) 
        if y not in d and (d.__setitem__(y, None) or True)]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If a simple two-liner is acceptable:

```
x = [4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1]
x = dict(map(None,x,[])).keys()
x.sort()
```

Or make two small helper functions (works for any sequence):

```
def unique(it):
    return dict(map(None,it,[])).keys()

def sorted(it):
    alist = [item for item in it]
    alist.sort()
    return alist

print sorted(unique([4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1]))
```

gives

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

And finally, a semipythonic one liner:

```
x = [4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1]
x.sort() or [s for s, t in zip(x, x[1:] + [None]) if s != t]
```

Comment: I like the new functions, makes it easy to just drop code into newer versions of python.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, Python 2.2 *does* have sets, but under the "sets" module, so this will get you a long way:

```
from sets import Set
myList = list(Set(myList))
# now we're duplicate-free, a standard sorting might be enough
myList.sort()
```

Comment: +1 because this is close to the in-built capabilities of newer Python versions: `list(set(myList))` --and if for some strange reason you wanted to, you could make it identical with `from sets import Set as set`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best answer is to use a binary tree:

```
# Make yield work in Python 2.2
from __future__ import generators

class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.value = value

    def add(self, value):
        if value == self.value:
            return
        if value < self.value:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = TreeNode(value)
            else:
                self.left.add(value)
        else:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = TreeNode(value)
            else:
                self.right.add(value)

    def __iter__(self):
        if self.left is not None:
            for value in self.left:
                yield value
        yield self.value
        if self.right is not None:
            for value in self.right:
                yield value

class DedupeSorter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def add(self, value):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = TreeNode(value)
        else:
            self.root.add(value)

    def __iter__(self):
        if self.root is None:
            return []
        else:
            return self.root.__iter__()

def dedupe_and_sort(l):
    sorter = DedupeSorter()
    for value in l:
        sorter.add(value)
    return list(sorter)
```

Definitely not idiomatic, but should be fast. It basically creates a tree-based set and iterates over it. I don't have Python 2.2 so hopefully it works :p